# In Forge Viewer Autodesk v7 LineDashMaterial and color for LineBasicMaterial not working

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

I am trying to add Lines of two different material i.e. LineDashedMaterial and LineBasicMaterial using Three.js in Forge viewer v7. LineDashedMaterial  not showing dashed pattern and material color in scene and sceneAfter but working in overlays scene same for LineBasicMaterial. but my requirement is to add line in scene and sceneAfter. can anyone tell me solution for this. thanks in advance.

```
 let geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
 geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
                        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 100));
let  material = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({color: 0xFF0000,
                                              dashSize: 3,
                                              gapSize: 1});
geometry.computeLineDistances();
geometry.lineDistancesNeedUpdate = true;
viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial('material', material, true);
let line= new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
viewer.impl.sceneAfter.add(line);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Engineering has now been made aware of the issue and will fix this in upcoming releases.

For now as a workaround you can switch off the DepthTarget option for `sceneAfter` to fix MRT support - see demo [here](https://output.jsbin.com/fiwadac/):

```
NOP_VIEWER.impl.sceneAfter.skipDepthTarget = true;
NOP_VIEWER.impl.sceneAfter.skipIdTarget = true;
```

But I was able to render the dashed pattern with Viewer v7.11 with `sceneAfter` (on Chrome v70 though)? Is the output in the screenshot what you are after? [Here's my live demo](https://jsbin.com/fiwadac/edit)...

[image]

Comment: yes I want same output that shown in screenshot, but on your live demo line is not showing. I am using viewer V7.0.0 and chrome v80.

Comment: Can confirm to be able to reproduce the issue on Chrome 80 - will let Engineering know to look into this and get back soon. Thanks!

Comment: still i am not getting output as expected. so for now I am using overlayScene. how can I confirm means do you want any screenshot or something?